# How to save edittext data so it be displayed when recreating the activity again?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have 2 simple activities, i the 1st one I used a button to take me to the 2nd, and in the 2nd there are some edittexts. Problem is that when hiting the back button on 2nd activity and then return to it, all data that entered in the edittexts are disappeared. I read that edittext data by default will be restored when the activity recreated but it's not happening. any help ?

Here is my simple 2nd activity code :

```
 @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bmi);

    final EditText ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final EditText ed3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    final EditText ed4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    final EditText ed5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    final EditText ed6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    final TextView tvb5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvb5);
    final TextView tvb6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvb6);
```

Comment: look at this link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: Thanks @Josef but I've already viewed this page and it doesn't work.